# Deadlock in MySQL trigger with embeded select query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, rdbms, database-deadlocks

I am having problems with `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` that causes deadlocks while inserting 2 or more **server_seed_use**'s at the same time.

I want to get rid of deadlocks (if possible) so I won't need to handle them on the app level. **server_seed_use** table will have literally millions if not billions of records. Inserts have to be performant and `uniqueIndex(serverSeedId, nonce)` is necessary so single **server_seed** never has multiple **server_seed_use** with same `nonce`.

Partial DB schema connected with this issue:

```
CREATE TABLE `server_seed` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`seed` CHAR(64) COLLATE \ "utf8_general_ci\" NOT NULL
    ,`hash` CHAR(64) COLLATE \ "utf8_general_ci\" NOT NULL
    ,`userId` INT NULL
    ,UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_caf256dbf86619a07597158267`(`seed`)
    ,UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_ea5ad02726433cb3e6969e65e3`(`hash`)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `server_seed_use` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`clientSeed` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
    ,`nonce` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL
    ,`serverSeedId` INT NULL
    ,INDEX `IDX_3b9f114a6190aae9cf7b0aeaab`(`nonce`)
    ,UNIQUE INDEX `IDX_2b872fdbfb8da47ca2744c53a8`(`serverSeedId`, `nonce`)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON server_seed_use
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE nextNonce INT;

        SET nextNonce = (SELECT MAX(nonce) FROM server_seed_use WHERE serverSeedId=NEW.serverSeedId); <--- I am convinced this is causing deadlocks
        IF (nextNonce IS NULL) THEN
            SET nextNonce = -1;
        END IF;

        SET NEW.nonce=nextNonce + 1;
    END
```

It is supposed to update nonce (set on insert) like this:

```
user_1(id: 1)
    server_seed_1(id: 1, owner: 1)
        server_seed_use_1(id: 1, serverSeedId: 1, nonce: 0)
        server_seed_use_2(id: 2, serverSeedId: 1, nonce: 1)
        server_seed_use_5(id: 5, serverSeedId: 1, nonce: 2)
    server_seed_2(id: 2, owner: 1)
        server_seed_use_3(id: 3, serverSeedId: 2, nonce: 0)
        server_seed_use_4(id: 4, serverSeedId: 2, nonce: 1)
user_2(id: 2)
    server_seed_3(id: 3, owner: 2)
        server_seed_use_6(id: 6, serverSeedId: 3, nonce: 0)
        server_seed_use_7(id: 7, serverSeedId: 3, nonce: 1)
```

Query that triggers a deadlock looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `server_seed_use`(`id`, `clientSeed`, `nonce`, `serverSeedId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, "clientSeed", DEFAULT, 1)
```

If executed only once or after the previous query has finished, works just fine but once executed concurrently 2 or more times the deadlock happens.

I tested different locking read mechanisms for select query (`SELECT MAX(nonce) FROM server_seed_use WHERE serverSeedId=NEW.serverSeedId`):

1. without or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`:

   `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.`
2. `FOR UPDATE`:

   `ER_CANT_UPDATE_USED_TABLE_IN_SF_OR_TRG: Can't update table 'server_seed_use' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` after the deadlock happens:

```
| InnoDB |      |
=====================================
2019-01-04 15:01:26 0x7fa1a642d700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 10 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1733 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 67024 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 68757
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 130200
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 81336
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 203699, OS waits 112137
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 145754, OS waits 1538
RW-sx spins 11622, rounds 72192, OS waits 223
Spin rounds per wait: 203699.00 RW-shared, 145754.00 RW-excl, 6.21 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2019-01-04 02:23:41 0x7fa1bf907700 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 1909787, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 608, OS thread handle 140332680378112, query id 36689 172.17.0.10 test
INSERT INTO `server_seed_use`(`id`, `clientSeed`, `nonce`, `serverSeedId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'aaa', DEFAULT, 1)
Foreign key constraint fails for table `test`.`server_seed_use`:
,
CONSTRAINT `FK_317cca594917646e8d2667d8317` FOREIGN KEY (`serverSeedId`) REFERENCES `server_seed` (`id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index IDX_2b872fdbfb8da47ca2744c53a8 tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 3 fields;
0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
1: SQL NULL;
2: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

But in parent table `test`.`server_seed`, in index PRIMARY,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000001d2419; asc \$ ;;
2: len 7; hex bf0000019c0110; asc ;;
3: len 30; hex 326431623961656431633066316431396630383030363032353037646261; asc 2d1b9aed1c0f1d19f0800602507dba; (total 64 bytes);
4: len 30; hex 376635626535643763393761373036613635663331316531643561333334; asc 7f5be5d7c97a706a65f311e1d5a334; (total 64 bytes);
5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc ;;

---

## LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

2019-01-04 14:45:33 0x7fa1a67fc700
**_ (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1980933, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1114, OS thread handle 140332419888896, query id 153107 172.17.0.10 test
INSERT INTO `server_seed_use`(`id`, `clientSeed`, `nonce`, `serverSeedId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, "clientSeed", DEFAULT, 1)
_** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 21479 page no 4 n bits 72 index IDX_2b872fdbfb8da47ca2744c53a8 of table `test`.`server_seed_use` trx id 1980933 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

**_ (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1980930, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 1113, OS thread handle 140332259854080, query id 153101 172.17.0.10 test
INSERT INTO `server_seed_use`(`id`, `clientSeed`, `nonce`, `serverSeedId`) VALUES (DEFAULT, "clientSeed", DEFAULT, 1)
_** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 21479 page no 4 n bits 72 index IDX_2b872fdbfb8da47ca2744c53a8 of table `test`.`server_seed_use` trx id 1980930 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 80000001; asc ;;
1: len 4; hex 80000000; asc ;;
2: len 4; hex 80000001; asc ;;

\*\*\* (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 21479 page no 4 n bits 72 index IDX_2b872fdbfb8da47ca2744c53a8 of table `test`.`server_seed_use` trx id 1980930 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

## \*\*\* WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

## TRANSACTIONS

Trx id counter 1980956
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1980956 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 479
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421808177219408, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)

---

## FILE I/O

I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
3815 OS file reads, 418691 OS file writes, 261409 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s

---

## INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX

Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
merged operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 2 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
0.00 hash searches/s, 0.00 non-hash searches/s

---

## LOG

Log sequence number 6612985217
Log flushed up to 6612985217
Pages flushed up to 6612985217
Last checkpoint at 6612985208
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
165104 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second

---

## BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY

Total large memory allocated 137428992
Dictionary memory allocated 855236
Buffer pool size 8192
Free buffers 1024
Database pages 7159
Old database pages 2622
Modified db pages 0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 17329, not young 362652
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 3754, created 155998, written 162468
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 7159, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]

---

## ROW OPERATIONS

0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=1, Main thread ID=140332486358784, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 5343638, updated 573, deleted 0, read 5746447
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s

---

# END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
```

@**Edit1**: I couldn't fit my answer to **@krokodilko** in the comment so I am writing it here.

I would rather avoid **2+3** solution since it creates even more problems.

Option **1+4** looks interesting. I already added `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK` check in the "critical" part of the app + retry logic. So by only adding **1** my issue has been partially resolved.

However, there are a lot of `ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK`'s happening which means there have to be a lot of retries (not really performant I assume). I would like to at least try to reduce the amount of deadlocks if it's not possible to get entirely rid of them.

As for query in **4** I think you meant

```
SELECT id INTO some_variable FROM server_seed_use WHERE serverSeedId = NEW.serverSeedId FOR UPDATE;
```

, since I am inserting `server_seed_use`'s instead of `server_seed`. Correct me if I am wrong.

I am not a MySQL expert but I think this lock will not be enough. It will protect all existing `server_seed_use`'s with specific `serverSeedId` but won't protect against inserting new `server_seed_use` with `serverSeedId`. Does it make sense? If so, is this possible to lock all inserts or based on `serverSeedId`, so there can be only one `server_seed_use` with specific `serverSeedId` inserting at the time.

Comment: What version of Mysql do you use?

Comment: @krokodilko `5.7.10`.

Comment: How many parallel inserts can be performed for the same `serverSeedId` at the same time? 10 per minute, 100 per minute, 1000 per minute ? Why did you show the definition of the table `server_seed` if the transaction only affects `server_seed_use` table, are they somehow connected? Can the `serverSeedId INT NULL` column really contain empty values? Does the `serverSeedId` column have a relation to the` id` column in the `server_seed` table?

Comment: I would say up to max 500 inserts per minute. I showed the definition of `server_seed` because there is a one to many relation between `server_seed` and `server_seed_use` (`server_seed`.`id` <=> `server_seed_use`.`serverSeedId`). To be honest, I didn't even notice the `serverSeedId INT NULL` until now... It was generated by the ORM and I guess it can be changed to `serverSeedId INT NOT NULL` if necessary.

Comment: "500 inserts per minute" for each `server_seed`. So for example for 10 `server_seed`'s there could be up to 5000 inserts per minute. From my estimations, there could be up to 250 concurrently writing `server_seed`'s (only few will be writing at full pace) so we're roughly looking at 100k inserts per minute.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the answer to the question** (or - this is only a partial answer).
Just the below text is too long to fit in the comment, so I give it as an answer to the question

---

Which ORM ? Hibernate, MyBatis, Toplink ... ?

Anyway, this deadlock is most likely due to the way MySql handles [InnoDB index gap locks](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/), although one would have to debug the code to be 100% sure (one would have to spend more time experimenting).

You have a few options:

1. catch the deadlock exception, rollback and repeat the whole transaction.
2. change the isolation level from repeatable read (default) to read committed.
3. enable the **innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog** system variable (not recommended since it is now deprecated - see [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html))
4. use an additional SELECT FOR UPDATE to lock some record in order to serialize all transactions (probably the best would be `SELECT * FROM server_seed WHERE id = NEW.serverSeedId FOR UPDATE`).

Options 2+3 probably will fix the deadlock problem, but most likely they will not be satisfying, because you will get "duplicate key error" instead - this is due to a flaw in the logic of the trigger (I will leave it now because it would require a longer explanation).

1 + 4 options remains the best.

Option 1 is obvious - must be implemented somewhere in the code.

Option 4 - You can try adding `SELECT id INTO some_variable FROM server_seed WHERE id = NEW.serverSeedId FOR UPDATE` as the first instruction in the trigger (assumming that **there is a record with this id in this table `server_seed`**). Alternatively, try to add it at the beginning of the transaction - I just do not know how to do it in your ORM.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I will try these changes tomorrow and report back to you. I am using `TypeORM` but that shouldn't really matter since I write triggers/procedures in migration files using standard SQL.

Comment: I couldn't fit my answer in the comment so I appended it to the main post.